# Importing data from a large file into a 2d Array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to import a large data file and insert the information into a 2D array. The file has around 19,000 lines, and consists of 5 columns. My code is absolutely correct, there are no run time errors nor exceptions. Though, the problem is that when I try to print out data[15000][0], it says null. but my line does have 15,000 lines and it should print out the element inside the array. But when I print out data[5000][0], it works. What could possibly be wrong?  I have 19,000 cities in 19,000 different lines, but it seems like when It goes around 10,000+ nothing gets stored in the 2d array. Help please

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.IOException;



 public class Data1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try{
      FileReader file = new FileReader("/Users/admin/Desktop/population.csv");
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(file);

        String title = in.readLine();
        String[][] data = new String[20000][5];
        int currentRow = 0;
        String current;


        int i = 0;
       String temp;
       while ((temp = in.readLine()) !=null)
        {
            String[]  c = new String[5];
            String line = in.readLine().replaceAll("\"", "");  //changing the format of the data input 
            c = line.split(",");
            c[1] = c[1].replace(" ", "");


          for (int j = 0; j <data[0].length; j++)
            {
                current = c[j];
                data[i][j] = c[j];

            }

            i++;
         }

         System.out.println(data[15000][0]);

    }
         catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: plz check the size of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're throwing away a line on each loop.

```
while (in.readLine() != null)
```

should be

```
String temp;
while ((temp = in.readLine()) != null)
```

And then no calls to .readLine() inside the loop but refer to "temp".

Comment: *String line =temp.replaceAll("\"", "");*  - Did you use temp like this??

Comment: ya.. seems like a typo... "\"(").. Did the program run?

Answer (score 0):

Read line only once...

```
  String line=null;
         while ((line=in.readLine()) !=null)  // reading line once here
        {
            String[]  c = new String[5];
            line = line.replaceAll("\"", "");  //
            c = line.split(",");
            c[1] = c[1].replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your errors are the loops

```
while (in.readLine() !=null)
        {
            String[]  c = new String[5];
            String line = in.readLine().replaceAll("\"", "");  //changing the format of the data input 
            c = line.split(",");
            c[1] = c[1].replace(" ", "");
```

Each time you invoke in.readLine() it reads a line,so you are skipping one line each time since you are calling readline twice(thus reading two lines) but storing only the second line.

You should replace it with. 
String line=in.readLine();

```
while (line !=null)
        {
            String[]  c = new String[5];
            line.replaceAll("\"", "");  //changing the format of the data input 
            c = line.split(",");
            c[1] = c[1].replace(" ", "");
//whatever code you have
//last line of the loop
line=in.readLine();
```

Can you provide us with a couple of lines of your file? And are you sure that all the file is formatted correctly ?